# Create a live updating "graph" in scene

Tags: python, vpython

I am currently using visual python with Kinect in order to track movement data of a person's right hand. With the program I have now, a person's body is tracked with a skeleton shown on the screen. I am looking to plot spheres that live update and grow based on when a person moves their hand more frequently in that area. Basically these spheres would represent movement density. I am not having any luck getting the spheres to update though. Any/all help will be appreciated, thanks!

Below is the code that I have for the spheres. I didn't include the skeleton code, as that is working correctly. I am an amateur at VPython/coding in general, so it may not be the most efficient or organized code

```
nbins = 2
bincount = 0

xpos = p2.x
ypos = p2.y
zpos = p2.z

xaxis = numpy.linspace(min(xpos), max(xpos), 2)
yaxis = numpy.linspace(min(ypos), max(ypos), 2)
zaxis = numpy.linspace(min(zpos), max(zpos), 2)

###initialize i,j,k???

for i in range(1, nbins):
    for j in range(1, nbins):
        for k in range(1, nbins):
            findpoints = find(p2.x >= xaxis[i] & p2.x <= xaxis[i+1] & p2.y >= yaxis[j] & p2.y <= yaxis[j+1] & p2.z >= zaxis[k] & p2.z <= zaxis[k+1])
        count = length(findpoints)
        i = i+1
        j = j+1
        k = k+1

        gridcount[i,j,k] = count
        count = 0

total = sum(sum(sum(gridcount)))
gridP = gridcount/total


for i in irange(1, nbins):
    xcenter = numpy.mean(xaxis[i],xaxis[i+1])
    for j in jrange(1, nbins):
        ycenter = numpy.mean(yaxis[j],yaxis[j+1])
        for k in krange(1, nbins):
            zcenter = numpy.mean(zaxis[k], zaxis[k+1])
            r = gridP(i,j,k)
            binsphere = sphere(radius = r, color = blue)
            hold
            axes3d.plot_surface(xcenter, ycenter, zcenter)
```

Comment: By the way, I want these sphere to show up in the scene with the skeleton, so as the skeleton's right hand is moving, it looks like it is touching/moving through the spheres

Comment: it would help if you posted some of the code you have... If you've attempted to get it working and it's not, post what you have. People will be much more willing to help with a specific problem than a 'how do I do this?' question.